# How to subtract from list of numbers individually?

Tags: jquery, list, html-table, subtraction

What I want to do is subtract from list on numbers just one number.
For example I have in a table following numbers and I want to subtract 4000:

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
      <td>result</td>
      <td>start</td>
   <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>4000</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

A perfect result would look like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
      <td>result</td>
      <td>start</td>
   <tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2500</td>
      <td>3500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4000</td>
      <td>4000</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a link what I've tried already:

http://jsfiddle.net/tiitremmel/LBjVJ/9/

Comment: By subtract, you mean remove?  Not subtract from each number?

Comment: stared at your question and the jsfiddle code and have no idea what you're trying to do. please clarify

Comment: jes, not each but from total. like in sample - 3000, 3500, 4000 and i want to subract 4000. result 3000 = 0, 3500 = 2500, 4000 = 4000got the point?

Comment: @Tiit: I'm confused, what are you trying to do?  How do you get 2500 from 3500 and 4000?

Comment: 3000 + 3500 + 4000 = 10500 if subtract 4000 i got result 6500. so but i want to do it like this - at first, since 4000 is bigger than 3000 i subtract 4000 from 3000 and i got result 1000, so i take the next one (witch is 3500) and i subtract from this the rest 1000 and i got 2500, and since the last 4000 were not touched it will stay the same

Comment: @Tiit: Oh, that makes sense now.

Comment: you have to subtract the leftover till the number is zero that you wanted to subtract

Comment: is it even possible? without like thousands if's

Comment: @Tiit: I think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CuKW/21/)

EDIT: New Version!

```
var subtract = 4000;

$('#tbl tbody tr').each(function(){
    var value = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
    var $result = $(this).find('td:eq(0)');

    if(subtract >= value){
        $result.text(0);
        subtract -= value;
    }
    else if(subtract <= 0){
        $result.text(value);
    }
    else{
        $result.text(value-subtract);
        subtract -= value;
    }
});
```

Comment: almost - problem is when you change the var 4000 to like 4100 then second row first td is correct (2400) but the third should be still 4000 since the second is not zero, but now it is 1600

Comment: much better! i'm also working on it, but i'm stuck now with var bigger than 4800 and smaller than 3000. where i'm trying to reach is that the var can be max same big as start column total (in this case 10500), but usually smaller. You're really helpful! thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tiit: I actually updated this answer a million times, try the newest version.

Comment: it Works! like a charm! - my first version of same result were over 200 rows javascript - Awesome - Really great thanks!

Comment: @Rocket - well done deciphering what was actually being requested

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a row that has the first cell as your target number then try:

```
var targetNumber = 4000;

// Note, better to use the ID of the table instead of 'table' here
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var tCell = $(this).find('td:first');
  if (parseInt(tCell.text()) == targetNumber) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```